# Fin de numeros en vector en c

Tags: c

Estoy empezando a programar y estoy haciendo una practica en lenguaje c y no consigo resolver una parte.
Debe parar de pedir números cuando se ingresa (-1) hasta ahora tengo esto pero no me funciona.
¿Podéis ayudarme?
Muchas gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void main(){
 
int vector[50];
int i;

 
for (i=0; i<50; i++){
   printf( "ingrese 50 numeros enteros. Numero %d\n", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
}
 
int mayor, menor;
mayor = vector[0]; //Le asignamos el primer elemento del array
menor = vector[0]; //Así empezamos a comparar
 
for (i=0; i<50; i++){
    if (vector[i]> mayor){
    mayor=vector[i];
    }
    if (vector[i]< menor){
    menor=vector[i];
    }
     if(i<0) {
        puts("Numero no valido. El programa se cierra");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);
printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);
}
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es interrumpir al usuario deberías de agregar la condicional `if(i<0)` dentro del ciclo for donde se le piden los datos al usuario... Si no ya es un poco tarde para interrumpirlo.

Answer (score 2):

> Debe parar de pedir números cuando se ingresa (-1)

Entonces debes comprobar el número introducido por el usuario y, si es -1, abandonar el bucle.

En programación, *comprobar* suele implicar un `if`, y *abandonar un bucle*, un `break`:

```
for (i=0; i<50; i++){
   printf( "ingrese 50 numeros enteros. Numero %d\n", i+1);
   scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
   if (vector[i]==-1) break;
}
```